# Ionic Pagination starting

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, pagination

I am trying to create a pagination feature but I feel stuck. I am not sure if I am on the right track...

in my view, I have an ng-repeat=" res in result", and at the end of the page i placed the following:

```
   <ion-infinite-scroll on-infinite="loadMore()" distance="1%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
```

then in the controller, i wrote this:

```
    var i=1; 
    $http.get( "http://website/search/"+i).success(function(response){
      i++; 
    $scope.result=(response) 
    });

    }
```

each pages returns a json containing 15 elements. What I want to do is when i reach the end, I want to load the next 15 in the result to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch next 15 item in `loadMore` function in controller as you write `on-infinite="loadMore()"` in `ion-infinite-scroll`

Write function as follow in your controller

```
$scope.result = [];
var i=1;
$scope.loadMore = function(){
   $http.get( "http://website/search/"+i).success(function(response){
      i++; 
      $scope.result.push(response);
   });
}
```

[Check Example](http://codepen.io/elm/pen/Becqp)

Comment: it doesn't work, i consoled.logged everything. It doesn't seem to push :/

Comment: check example given in link and try to follow this

Answer (score 0):

Hears how I have implemented `infinite-scroll` in my app

```
<ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="!loadMorePeople" on-infinite="loadPeople()" distance="1%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
```

**loadPeople()** loads all the scrolled data, it's code is bellow

```
$scope.loadMorePeople=false;


$scope.loadPeople = function() {

       if($scope.peoples != null){

          $http({
              method: "get",
              url: baseUrl+"company-members?page="+$scope.pagePeople,
              withCredentials: true,
              headers: {
                'Accept' : 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'Authorization' : ''+window.localStorage.getItem("token_type")+' '+window.localStorage.getItem("token")
              }
            })
                .success(function(data) {

                    if(data.length > 0){

                      var newPeople = data;
                      $scope.temp = $scope.peoples.concat(newPeople);
                      $scope.peoples = arrayUnique($scope.temp, 'id');

                        function arrayUnique(collection, keyname) {
                            var output = [], 
                                keys = [];

                            angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
                                var key = item[keyname];
                                if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                                    keys.push(key);
                                    output.push(item);
                                }
                             });
                            return output;
                       };

                       ++$scope.pagePeople;
                       $scope.$broadcast("scroll.infiniteScrollComplete");

                    }else{
                      $scope.loadMorePeople=true;
                      $scope.$broadcast("scroll.infiniteScrollComplete");
                    }

                })
                .error(function(data, status) {
                });
          }

          $scope.$broadcast("scroll.infiniteScrollComplete");

    };
```

I too had the same problem as you for some reason .push() was not working so I did this workaround.

I took the `data` checked if it's not null in `if(data.length > 0){}` and then used `.concat(newPeople)`  to merge them  and finally used `arrayUnique($scope.temp, 'id')` to make sure that there is no duplicate entity.

It's also a good idea to use `ng-if="!loadMorePeople"` it help to stop the call if there is no data left to fetch else the call will continously go on.

I hope this solves your problem. Let me know if you need any help :D